# Sorting R data frame by column with long strings

Tags: r, sorting

How can I sort R data by a column that consists of long strings? The following example illustrates my question:

```
> a = matrix(NA, nrow=4, ncol=3)
> a[,1] = c(1,2,3,4)
> a[,2] = c("gene001_10M","gene002_10M","gene001_50M","gene002_50M")
> colnames(a) = c("value","sortkey","other")
> a = as.data.frame(a)
> a
  value     sortkey other
1     1 gene001_10M  <NA>
2     2 gene002_10M  <NA>
3     3 gene001_50M  <NA>
4     4 gene002_50M  <NA>
```

When I sort on 'a' now, the sortkey seems to be read from right to left, leaving 'a' unchanged:

```
> b = a[sort(a$sortkey),]
> b
  value     sortkey other
1     1 gene001_10M  <NA>
2     2 gene002_10M  <NA>
3     3 gene001_50M  <NA>
4     4 gene002_50M  <NA>
```

My goal, however, is:

```
> b
  value     sortkey other
1     1 gene001_10M  <NA>
3     3 gene001_50M  <NA>
2     2 gene002_10M  <NA>
4     4 gene002_50M  <NA>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have `numbers`, `alphabets` etc it would be better to use `mixedorder` from `gtools`, though here it works with `order` alone

```
  a[order(as.character(a$sortkey)),]
  #  value     sortkey other
  #1     1 gene001_10M  <NA>
  #3     3 gene001_50M  <NA>
  #2     2 gene002_10M  <NA>
  #4     4 gene002_50M  <NA>
```

Also, using `sort` will get you the `values` instead of the `index`

```
   sort(as.character(a$sortkey))
   #[1] "gene001_10M" "gene001_50M" "gene002_10M" "gene002_50M"
```

Or otherwise, you have to specify `index.return=TRUE` which is by default `FALSE` in `sort`

```
   sort(as.character(a$sortkey), index.return=TRUE)
   #$x
  #[1] "gene001_10M" "gene001_50M" "gene002_10M" "gene002_50M"

  #$ix
  #[1] 1 3 2 4
```

Then, use

```
   a[sort(as.character(a$sortkey), index.return=TRUE)$ix,]
  #  value     sortkey other
  #1     1 gene001_10M  <NA>
  #3     3 gene001_50M  <NA>
  #2     2 gene002_10M  <NA>
  #4     4 gene002_50M  <NA>
```

Also,

```
  library(gtools)
   mixedorder(as.character(a$sortkey))
   #[1] 1 3 2 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `order` with a `gsub` regular expression to remove the letters beforehand

```
a[order(gsub("[a-zA-Z]+", "", a$sortkey)),]
#    value     sortkey other
# 1     1 gene001_10M  <NA>
# 3     3 gene001_50M  <NA>
# 2     2 gene002_10M  <NA>
# 4     4 gene002_50M  <NA>
```

Comment: I searched and searched for a solution to order a data frame by two columns - one with a string and the other was a date. This gave me the first part - then I just added the column for the date. Kudos!